# ActiveAdmin not decorating show view

Tags: activeadmin, decorator, draper

I am using ActiveAdmin on my Rails project. I use Draper as decorator but I don't understand why the show view is not decorated. According to the [documentation](https://github.com/afiedler/active_admin/blob/master/docs/11-decorators.md) it should be working just adding the `decorate_with MyDecorator` in my ActiveAdmin resource.

Here is my code:

```
ActiveAdmin.register Home do
  ...
  decorate_with HomeDecorator

  show do
    attributes_table do # not being decorated
      row :content
      row :status
      row :image
      row :author_with_avatar
    end
  end
end
```

Does someone know what is wrong with my code ?

Comment: What version of ActiveAdmin are you using?

Comment: The 1.0.0 pre1 . Actually, the weird thing is some time it works and after restarting server it's not decorating anymore. Don't know what's wrong.

Comment: What is in the decorator? Maybe there is an issue in the decorator.

Answer (score 1):

When I've run into this problem, it's because I've [customized the controller's `find_resource` method](http://activeadmin.info/docs/2-resource-customization.html#customizing-resource-retrieval).  In that case be sure to return a manually decorated object:

```
def find_resource
  MyModel.find_by_some_unique_finder(params[:id]).decorate
end
```

If all else fails you can force it using this approach:

```
show
  attributes_table_for model.decorate do 
    row :decorator_method
    row(:custom_label) { |m| m.decorator_method }
```

See http://activeadmin.info/docs/6-show-pages.html for more details